Coax cables, impedance matching and BNC extensions
I'm trying to understand how to do proper measurements with a Voltage Differential Probe ( TT-SI 9010. This probe has an output impedance of 50ohm and has a BNC (It doesn't specify it in the data sheet but the characteristic impedance of this BNC is 50Ohms accordin to an answer I had in a previous question I asked) with at the output to connect it to an oscilloscope. The Diff. Probe data sheets  recomends using this probe with an 1MΩ input impedance oscilloscope.
The thing is that the DUT that I'm measuring and and the oscilloscope that I want to use are aroung 10 meters away.
I want to  bring the signal from the Diff probe, with a longer BNC, but I only have 75Ω cables and BNC to BNC adapters
Is this set up wrong for my aplication? or should I by a 10m Z0=50ohm impedance


What bandwidth is the probe? Signal? Would you mind a 10 or 50ns blip in the waveform?

In the data sheet says that its a 70MHz probe. The signal comes from a GDT (Gas discharge Tube) and I need to see its behavior in a  50ns  time window to accurately measure is Breakdown

We can easily model situations like this using simulators like Micro-cap 12: -


The top trace is the originating pulse of 10 ns with a rise and fall time of 10 ns
The next trace is after the 50 Ω source impedance i.e. right at the cable start
The next trace is at the junction of 50 Ω and 75 Ω cables
The bottom trace is after 10 metres of 75 Ω cable into an open circuit

Things to note in the bottom trace are the multiple glitches that are like echoes every 150 ns. These you have to be aware of because they could disrupt your view if the original pulse was (say) 500 ns long: -

On this occasion it doesn't really matter whether the final load on the right was 1 MΩ or 2 MΩ.

Thats amazing... Thank you very much. I will defenetely play around with this simulator

Any problems getting it going just ask.
